# In Vim, I'm trying to have all class methods fold automatically when I open a file

Tags: vim, php, gvim, code-folding

When I open a PHP file that contains a class, how can I have Vim automatically fold the document up like this?:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you want to set your 'foldmethod' option to "syntax"?

```
:set fdm=syntax
```

If this works as desired, you can put that command in `~/.vim/ftplugin/php.vim` (`~/vimfiles/ftplugin/php.vim` on Windows) to make it automatic when you open a PHP buffer.

Edit: I realized that you may want the class declaration not to be folded by default.  To do so, try:

```
:set foldlevel=1
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that this combination should work:

```
set foldmethod=indent
set foldlevelstart=4
```

You might need to adjust the value of `foldlevelstart`.

If you only want the functions themselves to be collapsed (and not any blocks within them), you may also want to adjust the value of `foldnestmax` to be equal to what you set in `foldlevelstart`.

If you are doing that to have a bird's view of your code you might be intereted by [TagList](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273) or [TagBar](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3465).